# How can I select an element by its index with $()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using vanilla JavaScript I can Write:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1")[2]
```

To specify an element by its index, in this case it's the third element.

Can I do the same thing with $()?

Is it possible to get an element by its index with this function?

Edit:
I'm sorry for not clarifying my problem, this is my code:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1")[2].innerHTML = "Hello";
$("h1")[2].text("Hi");
```

The result will be the text changed to "Hello" not "Hi".
How can I choose the third element the same way and change its text?

Comment: `$("h1")[2]` will get you the 3rd `<h1>` element, if that's what you mean

Comment: but it won't give you the jquery wrapper.

Comment: `$("h1")[2]`   ???

Comment: why jquery in this day and age?

Comment: @DanielA.White because it's convenient for a lot of things, though it's true that native browser APIs do almost everything now

Comment: *Using vanilla JavaScript I can write: `document.querySelectorAll("h1")[2]`* <-- Yeah, but you shouldn't because scanning for all the `h1` elements, just to throw that collection away and only use the 3rd one is wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use DOM element `$('h1')[i]` or `$('h1').get(i)`
and also `$('h1').eq(i)`

Comment: Thanks, I used $('h1').eq(i) and it worked, I'm not sure why $('h1')[i] and $('h1').get(i) don't work though.

Comment: @azizaon they **do** work. What makes you think they don't?

Comment: The other notations (besides `.get(i)`) don't work when you continue to use the `.text()` method on them, since in those cases the result is not a jQuery object, but a pure DOM object, and the latter does not have the `.text()` method.

Comment: Ah right, well the OP didn't mention in the original question that a jQuery object was the desired result. However it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `document.querySelectorAll()` function in jQuery is `$()`.So you can write `$("h1")[2]`